# Drop a table with foreign key to it fails even with foreign_key_checks=0

Tags: mysql

I need to run `drop table pages` when other table has foreign key to it.

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uri` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pages_domain_unique` (`domain`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The referencing table:

```
CREATE TABLE `link_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `page_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `link_data_page_id_foreign` (`page_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `link_data_page_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `pages` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The script...

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
drop table drop table pages; --// the row I am failing with.
ALTER TABLE link_dataDROP FOREIGN KEY link_data_page_id_foreign;
ALTER TABLE link_data DROP COLUMN page_id;

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

I need to drop the table pages before i remove the referencing field. (complicated issue, dont asy why).

Why `foreign_key_checks=0` is not acting in this situation?

`Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: DROP TABLE`pag
  es`;)`
**UPDATE**
 the question is more about why the `foreign_key_checks=0` not affecting the script.  How to solve it its simple, just prioritise the script differently.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried set the cascade options ?

```
 CONSTRAINT `link_data_page_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `pages` (`id`)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

If not, try to declare the constraint as deferrable. When deleting the register itself, set deferred mode and then back.

If you were using phpMyAdmin go to the `Variables` section and disable `foreign key checks` to see whether this works.

Comment: I need to drop a table with a reference. the question is more about why the `foreign_key_checks=0` not affecting the script.

Comment: Ok, ``domain`` does not exists in table ``pages``. Take a look at ``drop table drop table pages; --// the row I am failing with.`` and let me know if this is the code you are executing against mysql. Update the script and code. I want to execute this in my environment. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, are you executing this in phpMyAdmin ?